# My Underground Hallow didn't spawn

Tags: terraria

My Underground Hallow didn't spawn... Because my Hallow was changed from my old forest to my new Hallow so what should I do?  I need souls of light and other things like cave crystals.

Answer (score 2):

The generation of the Underground Hallow biome isn't a column underneath the Hallow - it's one half of a V shape starting from the centre of the map's Underworld, the other side of which is either Corruption or Crimson (depending on which of these was initially on the map).

The [Terraria Wiki's Hardmode entry](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode) has an image showing an example of the V shape from the middle of one map - Hallow is on the left side of the V in this example.

Comment: Mine is too but I can't see a V just a strip of hallow

Comment: It is an X shape if it overlaps a Corruption or Crimson biome. Correct me if I am wrong.